# Button Click doesn't work on the remote view shared between two application

Tags: android, ipc, remoteview

I have created two application 
1. HostApp
2. MainApp

HostApp create a remoteview and share it with MainApp over IPC. The Layout inflated on RemoteView contains a button which click event is register using following code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")) ;
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0 , i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
timeView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.test_button, pi);
```

Still when the Main App is launched it shown the button but it click event doesn't work.

Comment: Could you attach the log if any errors present?

Comment: IT doesn't show any errors... it just don't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved now, the only challenge is with the line

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0 , i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

changed it to

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0 , i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); and it worked.